# Vertical align with subcaption package

Tags: subcaption, landscape

I'm using the `subcaption` package (`\usepackage{subcaption}`), but it seems that in landscape mode the the figure is not vertically centered.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[t]
\captionsetup{labelsep=quad, indention=9pt, textfont=sf}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{./img/divMassMarketfront.pdf}
    \caption{Diversified Mass Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.5, \sigma^2_2 = 0.5$}
\label{fig:divMassMarketfront}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{./img/specMassMarketfront.pdf}
    \caption{Specialized Mass Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.5, \sigma^2_2 = 0.2$}
    \label{fig:specMassMarketfront}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{./img/divNicheMarketfront.pdf}
    \caption{Diversified Niche Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.2, \sigma^2_2 = 0.5$}
    \label{fig:divNicheMarketfront}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}

    \includegraphics[width=13cm]{./img/specNicheMarketfront.pdf}
    \caption{Specialized Niche Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.2, \sigma^2_2 = 0.2$}
    \label{fig:specNicheMarketfront}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Market 1's share of total consumers (Z-axis) depending on parameter grid $\mu_1, \sigma^2_1$ (X,Y-axis) and Market 2's parameter. Computed with consumer distribution from Fig. \ref{fig:3D_Space}. X,Y-Axis view.}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}  
\captionsetup{labelsep=quad, indention=9pt, textfont=sf}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=11cm]{./img/divMassMarketside.pdf}
    \caption{Diversified Mass Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.5, \sigma^2_2 = 0.5$}
    \label{fig:divMassMarketside}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=11cm]{./img/specMassMarketside.pdf}
    \caption{Specialized Mass Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.5, \sigma^2_2 = 0.2$}
    \label{fig:specMassMarketside}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=11cm]{./img/divNicheMarketside.pdf}
    \caption{Diversified Niche Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.2, \sigma^2_2 = 0.5$}
    \label{fig:divNicheMarketside}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=11cm]{./img/specNicheMarketside.pdf}
    \caption{Specialized Niche Market Competitor $\mu_2 = 0.2,\sigma^2_2 = 0.2$}
    \label{fig:specNicheMarketside}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Market 1's share of total consumers (Z-axis) depending on parameter grid $\mu_1, \sigma^2_1$ (X,Y-axis) and Market 2's parameter. Computed with consumer distribution from Fig. \ref{fig:3D_Space}. Y-Axis view}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable! I am not having issues with your code. The only thing is that 13 or even 11 cm is too big for a page in `article`. You better do `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...`. Please try to do `\fbox{\includegraphics[...}` in order to see, if you are having white areas around your images, which you should crop away.

Comment: Ok, I did some tests. You images are too heigh for this page. Please do `\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{...` and increase this value as long as it stays in limits. You can increase the size if you crop everything away which is not needed. The `[t]` specifier for the first figure is not needed here.

Comment: For standard `article` with default font size and no `geometry` settings, the maximum size here is `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.85cm]`. Without an MWE of you, I can not give better advice.

Comment: Off-topic, but as wee need every mm here: You are missing a percent sign after each `subfigure`. It should be `\end{subfigure}%` at least for the 1., 3., ... image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @LaRiFaRi , the `crop` hint was exactly what I needed. Will adjust axes-labels and legends as well in R to save some space.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are too high for this page. Please do `\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{...` and increase this value as long as it stays in limits. You can increase the size if you crop everything away which is not needed. The `[t]` specifier for the first figure is not needed here.

For standard article with default font size and no geometry settings, the maximum size here is `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.85cm]`. Without an MWE of you, I can not give better advice.

Off-topic, but as wee need every mm here: You are missing a percent sign after each subfigure. It should be `\end{subfigure}%` at least for the 1., 3., ... image.